# two types of redirections on .htaccess getting error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to do two things using .htaccess

1. redirect non www (http://domain.com) to www (http://www.domain.com)
2. I am also trying to redirect mobiles to go for a different URL 
   (http://www.domain.com/mobile) from  (http://www.domain.com)

the code I am using:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebotmobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}"dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lgc|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}"palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
  RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/mobile [L,R=302]

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /default.htm [L]
    </IfModule>
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: I just cannot go to  http://domain.com but mobile redirection is working fine . Do I have anything wrong in top two lines? or the 2nd redirection anyway having conflicts with the first one.. my site is http://www.scbeverage.com/

Comment: Do you mean to say that "domain.com" is redirecting to www.domain.com/mobile?